# Does not execute if and elif statement in a recursive function that appends

Tags: python, if-statement, recursion, append

I don't understand why the `if` and `elif` statement with the `append` in it is not executed. I converted the `hht` and `hat` variable in so it can be compared.

```
a = {0: {'halbzeit_h_tore': '1', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '1'}, 
     1: {'halbzeit_h_tore': '0', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '0'}, 
     2: {'halbzeit_h_tore': '1', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '0'}, 
     3: {}
    }

 
played_games_of_the_day =[]

def check_1(**kwargs):
    hht = kwargs['halbzeit_h_tore']
    hat = kwargs["halbzeit_a_tore"]
    c = 0
    if hht == "-" and hat == "-":
        played_games_of_the_day.append(0)
        c += 1
        check_1(**a[c])
    elif int(hht) == int and int(hat) == int :
        c += 1
        played_games_of_the_day.append(1)
        check_1(**a[c])
    #if dict empty pass#
    elif not bool(a[c]):
        pass
    
    if all(x==0 for x in played_games_of_the_day):
            print("all zero")
    elif all(x==1 for x in played_games_of_the_day):
            print("all one")

check_1(**a[0])
print(played_games_of_the_day)
```

Comment: What is `int(hht) == int` supposed to do? `int(hht)` is a number. `int` on rhs is a class type.

Comment: O I didnt knew, just wanted that it looks up if it is a number

Comment: `int` is the name of a built-in [class / function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int), so testing if `int(hht) == int and int(hat) == int` will **never** be true. Type checking in Python should be done via the built-in [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) function. i.e. `if isinstance(hht, int): …`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To properly handle the values we need to consider the scenarios.

First, in the given code the values in the dictionary are `str` types. In general you can check the type of the variable with `isinstance` function. Let's start with some examples:

```
my_dict = {'str_type': '1', 'int_type': 1, 'bad_str_type': 'I am not a number'}

def get_int_value(my_input):
    if isinstance(my_input, int):
        # It is already an integer
        return my_input
    elif isinstance(my_input, str):
        # Needs to be converted
        return int(my_input) # Crashes for bad strings

get_int_value(my_dict['str_type']) # returns int 1
get_int_value(my_dict['int_type']) # returns int 1
get_int_value(my_dict['bad_str_type']) # Raises ValueError
```

So how can we handle the crash. We can check the input value before we try to make a number (Look Before You Leap, LBYL) or detect when it fails and recover from it (Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission, EAFP). The choice is up to the preference of the developer.

One way to check the string for a number is to use `my_input.isnumeric()`. There are other options such as Regular Expressions for more complicated requirements but I digress as it's too much for this scenario.

Using LBYL:

```
def get_int_value(my_input):
    if isinstance(my_input, int):
        # It is already an integer
        return my_input
    elif isinstance(my_input, str):
        # Needs to be converted
        # Negative numbers start with a '-'. isnumeric does not like it
        if (my_input.startswith('-') and my_input[1:].isnumeric())
            or my_input.isnumeric():
            return int(my_input)
        else:
            return None # Or anything else that is appropriate.
get_int_value(my_dict['str_type']) # returns int 1
get_int_value(my_dict['int_type']) # returns int 1
get_int_value(my_dict['bad_str_type']) # returns None
```

Using EAFP:

```
def get_int_value(my_input):
    if isinstance(my_input, int):
        # It is already an integer
        return my_input
    elif isinstance(my_input, str):
        # Needs to be converted
        try:
            return int(my_input) # If it is int like there's no problem
        except ValueError:
            # It wasn't int like
            return None # Or anything else that is appropriate.
get_int_value(my_dict['str_type']) # returns int 1
get_int_value(my_dict['int_type']) # returns int 1
get_int_value(my_dict['bad_str_type']) # returns None
```

Comment: Changed to : if hht.isdigit() and hat.isdigit(): and: elif isinstance(hht, str) and isinstance(hat, str):, now I am getting the error: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Never enter the if `if hht == "-" and hat == "-":` cause as you can see in your dictionary there is not value like that in it, and it never enters this elif `elif int(hht) == int and int(hat) == int :` cause your are comparing an integer with a type of variable, and that will always return False

Comment: Can you tell me how do i check if it is a number, because i tought i am doing this with comparing to int.

Comment: You can check if is an integer by using elif hht.isnumeric() and hat.isnumeric():

Comment: Also, `int(hht)` would likely raise a `ValueError` if `hht` is not converted to an `int`. Basically, the program would crash if it's not a number.

Comment: exactly, thats why it should check if is an integer before trying to convert it into one